# Angular's $location.$hash not consistently working

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to use Angular's $location service as follows :

```
function onMenuAction(rept, hier) {                     
  $location.url('index.html#/reportmaint?reptname=' + rept + "&hierarchy=" + hier); 
}
```

But it does NOT redirect to my reportmaint.html view.

Instead it's going straight to my dashboard.html, which is my index page in the routes.

The URL in the address bar as a result of the above $location.url call is this :

```
   http://localhost:49479/index.html#/#%2Freportmaint%3Freptname=CTPYHIER&hierarchy=true
```

But it's not changing to the reportmaint.html route at all.

If I, however, manually enter this URL Angular redirects to reportmaint.html as expected :

```
http://localhost:49479/index.html#/reportmaint?reptName=TEST
```

My sidebar.js started off like this with $location service injected :

```
 (function () { 
'use strict';

var controllerId = 'sidebar';
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
    ['$scope', '$route', '$location', '$window', 'config', 'routes', 'datacontext', 'userService', sidebar]);

function sidebar($scope, $route, $location, $window, config, routes, datacontext, userService) {
    var vm = this;

 // ... additional code ommitted

   function onMenuAction(rept, hier) {                  
     $location.url('index.html#/reportmaint?reptname=' + rept + "&hierarchy=" + hier);
    }
};
})();
```

I am missing something key in the understanding of the $location service. Hash mode vs. html5 mode ? Does this somehow affect what I'm trying to accomplish ?

thank you in advanced.

Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `index.html#` in the URL to make it work:

```
$location.url('/reportmaint?reptname=' + rept + "&hierarchy=" + hier);
```

An alternative to this is using **[`$location.path()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#path)** and **[`$location.search()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search)** to change the URL:

```
$location.path('/reportmaint').search({reptname: rept, hierarchy: hier});
```

Comment: $location.url() is working now ! And do you know why  $.location.$$hash is empty in my target page yet $$url is not --> $$url: "/reportmaint?reptname=CTPYHIER&hierarchy=true"

Comment: Why do you want to access the $location.$$hash property? if you want to access the query string parameter values you can use `$location.path()` which returns an object representation of your query parameters.

Comment: because $$hash works for me on a different page, namely on dashboard.html; but in this redirect scenario it doesn't, so I wanted to know why. Anyhow, your suggestion worked out so I won't fight it. thank you.